# JSON/Javascript: return INDEX of array object containing a certain property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Given a JSON object such as this:

```
{
  "something": {
    "terms": [
      {
        "span": [
          15,
          16
        ],
        "value": ":",
        "label": "separator"
      },
      {
        "span": [
          16,
          20
        ],
        "value": "12.5",
        "label": "number"
      }
    ],
    "span": [
      15,
      20
    ],
    "weight": 0.005,
    "value": ":12.5"
  }
 }
```

I asked a question about parsing the object out where label: number here:
[JSON/Javascript: return which array object contains a certain property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746939/json-javascript-return-which-array-object-contains-a-certain-property)

I got a sufficient answer there (use filter()), but now need to know the original index of the object.

This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050747/get-elements-index-after-using-filter) seems to have the answer, but I simply don't know enough about javascript to translate it into something useful for my particular problem.

The following code successfully returns the object.  Now I need to modify this to return the original index of the object:

```
var numberValue, list = parsed.something.terms.filter(function(a){
  return a.label==='number';
});
numberValue = list.length ? list[0].value : -1;
```

This needs to be a pure javascript solution, no external libraries, etc.

Comment: What you want to acheive ? what you expect from answer ? an example please.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Not sure what you mean.  The only thing I need returned is the index of the original object. This is requested in my question and is achieved by the approved answer.  Is there something specific I needed to do in order to make this question better? Happy to do so if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can modify the filter solution as within the filter you've lost the indexes.

The solution you've linked to uses the angular external library.

So here is a pure JS solution:

```
var numberValue = parsed.something.terms
    .map(function(d){ return d['label']; })
    .indexOf('number');
```

[Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: indexOf doesn't work in IE8, which may or may not be a big deal. The OP should make sure to add this function to the array prototype.

Comment: Yeah I assumed that since filter was already being used that map/indexOf would be OK

Comment: @frenchie, well, neither does `filter`.

Comment: Thanks.  IE8 compatibility is not needed.  OP

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach` and collect the indices of objects that satisfy the `a.label==='number'` predicate :

```
var target = parsed.something.terms;
var list = [];
target.forEach(function(element, index){
    if (element.label==='number') {
        list.push(index)
    };
});
var numberValue = list.length ? target[list[0]].value : -1;

console.log(list); // [1]
console.log(numberValue); // 12.5
```